# Compare string like '1,2,3' and '3,1,2' to be set as equals in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, compare

I have a strings like '1,2,3' and '3,1,2'in a list, is there any way to compare these two strings and check that they are the same?

I have a lis a = ['G1G2G3,G4,G10','G4,G1G2G3,G10], i need a[0] == a[1] to return TRUE

Comment: ...they aren't the same. `"1,2,3" != "3,1,2"`.

Comment: By what criteria? That the numbers separated by commas are the same? You'd need to manually implement that comparison by doing a `split` and `sort` or something.

Comment: What does that mean? Why are they equal? Is `"3,1,2"` also equal? And if it has spaces, like `"3,               1,            2"`? Or `"1-2-3"` or `"321"`? And what exactly do you find problematic in implementing this code? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you want to treat each string as a kind of `set`? Should `'3,1,1'` and `'1,3'` be considered equal?

Comment: `a = list(['1,2,3', '3,1,2'])`
`print(a[0]==a[1])`?

Comment: @chepner yes i want to see this string like equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each string to a `set`, and compare the results.

```
>>> set('1,2,3'.split(',')) == set('3,1,2'.split(','))
True
```